# Is the use of the word "opening" correct in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This context comes from the book "Black Rednecks And White Liberals" by Thomas Sowell

"Early Lebanese businesses in the United States were noted for “**opening** 16 to 18 hours daily,” utilizing “the assistance of the whole family."During the earlier rise of Chinese shopkeepers in Southeast Asia, sixteen-to-eighteen hour days were also common""

The word "**opening**" is confusing to me as I know that **"open"** means:

c. To begin business or operation: *The store opens early on Saturday.*(source thefreedictionary)

...so if the Lebanese businesses were noted for **"opening"** for me this means they were noted only for the hour they **began their operation** and not for when they **were closing**, but the sentence states both. Why? Is it just sloppy English?

Comment: Why do you have a problem with the continuous participle here? It's no different to *Early Lebanese businesses in the United States were noted for **having** long opening hours*, or *...were noted for **being** open from very early in the morning until very late at night*. The reference is to ***the state of being open***, not the actual "event" of opening the shop.

Comment: Well I written it in the post =P I don't know how to clarify it. The word "open" as far as I know, means "to begin" but the writer uses it as meaning "begin and end"

Comment: The word "open" has a range of meanings - including as a noun, ***the state of being open*** as well the verb sense ***to begin***. In your context, ***opening*** is simply alternative phrasing for ***being open***.

Comment: But it's not a noun in this case, right? What is it then? You said it's a "continuous participle"  participle is defined as "a word derived from a verb and used as an adjective, as in a laughing face" Is this an adjective then? Also I can find no definition of a noun "open" meaning "the state of being open" are you sure you didn't mean "open" as adjective("6. ready for business: the shops are open.")

Comment: Maybe format grammatical terminology has some different way of describing the usage, but I don't know how that would help you *understand* what's going on here. All I'm saying is that in your specific context, ***opening*** is semantically and syntactically precisely equivalent to ***being open*** (the two forms are interchangeable, and mean exactly the same thing).

Comment: Ok Thanks for that. I'll wait for someone maybe they'll explain in further or I''ll set a bounty on the post to attract some gramma masters :)

Comment: ...it's the same as *British high street banks were known **for closing early*** or ***...for closing on Saturday afternoons*** - the second of which is precisely equivalent ***...for being closed on Saturday afternoons*** (but for reasons I can't readily explain, it's not very idiomatic to use ***...for being closed early*** here).

Comment: @FumbleFingers. You've invested a lot of energy in this thread of comments. Please invest as much energy in a good answer that documents your position.

Comment: @JeffreyCarney: Gimmie a break, willya? It should be obvious from my comments that ***I can't answer OP's question*** the way he would like. But I ***can*** raise relevant factors that might be useful.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The answer to OP's question is, "Yes. This is sloppy English."

Comment: @JeffreyCarney:  I disagree - but if that's what you think then why don't *you* post your opinion as an answer?

Comment: *A few decades ago, British shops were prevented **from opening on Sunday*** OR ***...from being open on Sunday*** looks like essentially the same construction to me. Is the first of *those* "sloppy English"? Personally, I like it better than the second, but I wouldn't say either is "wrong".

Comment: You're right. "Open" is not a verb that means "to remain open" for a length of time, and, though it's understandable, it sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "British shops were prevented from opening on Sunday" is not the same as "“opening 16 to 18 hours daily,” because the latter suggests that you are opening something for 16 to 18 hours but you are not. You are opening it once in the morning or whatever the time is the business opens.

Comment: You can keep disagreeing with me if you like. But at the end of the day, I'm a native speaker, and the usage you're asking about is perfectly natural to me. If you don't think it's "logical", there's nothing I can do about that.

Comment: No, no, I believe that it's used that was and that it can be perfectly correct to do so, but can you see the logic I'm following in the last comment? Would you agree that based on this definitions of the word "open" somebody who is a not-native could have difficulty understanding this kind of sentence? Basically, what happens I think, is that you are right that it's used in that way, but we need someone to verbalize why it's correct. For now I will just accept it as a correct way of saying it without knowing why :)

Comment: Obviously *somebody who is a not-native (you) **does** have difficulty understanding this kind of sentence!* But maybe you should just classify it as "loose / sloppy English" and move on. It might be worth noting that both verb forms are acceptable and equivalent in *The shop **opens / is open** every day*. But with *The shop **opens / is open** LATE on Friday*, the first ("active") verb form strongly implies the shop ***isn't*** open earlier in the day on Fridays, but there's no such implication with ***is open*** (i.e. - ***remains*** open, perhaps after having opened very early that day).

Answer (score 0):

This is either a slangy usage, a crude usage, or an ego gratifying usage (authors, you know?).  The word *opening* does not mean the same thing as *to be open*.  Your understanding and your research is valid.  Despite the non-standard usage, only one meaning can be derived.

Comment: I would have to say that as a BrE speaker this use of _opening_ seems perfectly normal but perhaps not so elsewhere.

Comment: @mdewey - It's understood but I just can't find enough usage to support it being *normal* in either British or American English.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opening+eight+hours%2Copening+daily&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Copening%20daily%3B%2Cc0